# Add Request URI to URL Window Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iframe

I'm writing an htaccess file to redirect a subdomain on one server to another site with a different URL.  I want the original subdomain and file path in the URL Window, while the content of the site is an iframe with source of the second site.   I have it working, except in the URL window, the REQUEST_URI does not show.  It goes to the proper page, but the page path fails to show.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Exclude method to remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|admin\.php|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Here is the index file with the iframe redirect:

```
<?php 

$requesturi = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   

?>

<iframe src="http://mysecondsite.com<?php echo $requesturi ?>"
frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

So I want "http://www.myfirstsite.com/path1" to go to "http://www.mysecondsite.com/path1", and it works, but the problem is, the URL window only shows "http://www.myfirstsite.com" instead of "http://www.myfirstsite.com/path1"

Comment: It stays as http://www.myfirstsite.com/path1

Comment: If I click a new link from there, http://www.myfirstsite.com/path2 ... The URL stays as http://www.myfirstsite.com/path1 ... If I click first http://www.myfirstsite.com/ ... the next links leave the URL as http://www.myfirstsite.com/

Comment: The new site is in Wordpress, that could be it right?  They are simple href links indeed.

Comment: The fact that entering `http://www.myfirstsite.com/path1` stays **as is** shows there is nothing wrong with rewrite rules.

Comment: What it is is that you click on the links, but they are actually not 'myfirstsite.com', they are 'mysecondsite', so the first site .htaccess is not accessed, it's all through the new site, and for some reason the URL stays as what it was.